# update column with numbers in sqlite table

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, select, sql-update

This should be very simple but I cannot figure out how to do it. I would like to modify the values of two different columns. One from 1 to the total number of rows and the other one from the total of rows to one (basically increasing and decreasing number). I tried:

```
start = 0
end = number_of_rows + 1
c.execute('SELECT * FROM tablename') 
newresult=c.fetchall()

for row in newresult:

  start += 1
  end -= 1

  t = (start,)
  u = (end,)    

  c.execute("UPDATE tablename SET Z_PK = ?", t) ---> this will transform all rows with Z_PK since there is no where statement to limit
  c.execute("UPDATE tablename SET Z_OPT = ?", u)
```

The thing is that I don't know how I can add the "where" statement since I have no values I am sure for rows (like IDs number). A possibility would be to return the current row as the argument for "where" but I don't know how to do it...

Comment: Is there any INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column? Is this a WITHOUT ROWID table? IS there any constraint on these two columns?

Comment: There is no constraint. The problem is there was an integer primary key and in fact this is the one I want in increasing number (Z_PK). The problem was that I merge two databases and some Z_PK have the same number. I would like then to iterate the table and update new numbers.

Comment: So you have merged the two tables into a new table without a primary key constraint?

Comment: Oups sounds like I should not have done it. Yes I just did: c.execute("create table newTable as select * from table1 union select * from table2")

Comment: UNION removes duplicates; you might want to use UNION ALL instead (or not).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column, your table has an [internal `rowid` column](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid), which already contains the values you want:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET Z_PK = rowid,
    Z_OPT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable) + 1 - rowid
```